# This Question about how to merge data in excel

Tags: concatenation

I have 2 columns. One is the name of the student and second is percentage of student. In percentage column some cell percentage sign is missing.

I want the student name with the percentage combine in one column, what should i need to do get something like this :

```
Name   Marks    Total
ram     60%     ram 60%
Robin   50      i need data like this "Robin 50%"
```

Comment: Have a look into excel CONCATENATE() function, and have a try. Then share with us what you get/didn't..

Comment: yes i had tried but not getting appropriate answer which function i'm using is:-    =concatenate(A2," ",text(b2,"0%")) this formula working with those data which have percentage sing like (70%), but with percentage sign it giving value like this 5000% if marks value is 50.

Comment: good try.. the output is promising.. | 1st thing 1st.. the excel recognise 60% as 0.60 & 50 as 50 . That is the source of the problem. That's why u get 5000% , which is equivalent to 50 in numerical value. | towards solving it..  I suggest to use `cell("format",b2)` to 'see' the format of b2. Then use that info to determine whether to do `concatenate(A2," ",text(b2,"0%"))` or `concatenate(A2," ",b2,"%")` . Have a try

Comment: IF(B6<1,CONCATENATE(A6," ",TEXT(B6,"0%")),CONCATENATE(A6," ",B6,"%")) i used this formula and its working fine, your suggestion i already tried but its not given correct value for with Percentage value. But thank for your suggestion.

Comment: So it is solved ? btw..  if the mark is 100 (100 %) wouldn't it be a problem?

Comment: =IF(B2<=1,A2&TEXT(B2," #%"),A2&" "&B2&"%"), use this it will also work with 100(100%) value.

Comment: You may post it as an answer, as recommended by the [host](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). [ I take it as solved then.. ]

Comment: yes it is solved now